# Interface Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I have a file named main.ts which include the following code snippet :

```
interface bodyInfos {
    height?: any;
    mass?: any;
}

const calculateBmi = (user: bodyInfos) => {
    return user.mass / ( user.height ** 2 );
};

let foo: bodyInfos;
let bar: bodyInfos;

// Foo
foo.height = 172;
foo.mass = 75;
// Bar
bar.height = 180;
bar.mass = 90;

console.log('foo BMI', calculateBmi(foo) );
console.log('bar BMI', calculateBmi(bar) );
```

The problem is whenever I try to execute the file main.ts using the command: node main.ts I got an error on console saying:

```
interface bodyInfos {
          ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I need your support, please.

Comment: Node doesn't run TS code by default. You need to compile it to JavaScript and run that.

Comment: https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-with-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Found it, thank you @VLAZ for clarification,

What I did is that I needed to compile the main.ts into main.js using `tsc main.ts` and run the command `node main.js` on the new compiled file and voila it worked perfectly.

A little explanation here, Actually I tried to compile the file using ts-node but didn't work as excepted, the console output too many errors.